# PHP fetch data and insert into html table

Tags: php

```
SELECT date, DAYNAME(date) as day , time FROM booking WHERE date BETWEEN CURDATE() AND CURDATE() + INTERVAL 7 DAY
```

After query, will return result of day and its specific time. [query result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L1dtl.jpg)

and will populate the date into html table.

However, the real problem is that, when the result return more that 1 result, it will populate the table according to the number or result. [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3vhQ.jpg)

This are the PHP code that i use to loop through result ,

```
function checkHari() {

    $sql = "SELECT date, DAYNAME(date) as Hari , time FROM booking WHERE date BETWEEN CURDATE() AND CURDATE() + INTERVAL 7 DAY";
    $results = mysql_query($sql);
    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($results);

    return $results;
}

$check_hari = checkHari();


while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($check_hari)) {
 <?php if( $hari = 'Wednesday' ) { ?>
 <tr>
 <td>Wednesday</td>
 <?php if ($time >= 8 && $time < 10) {
  echo '<td id="Wednesday0810" class="blacked"><small>Booked</small></td>';
  } else {
  echo '<td></td>';
  } ?>
 <?php if ($time >= 10 && $time < 12) {
  echo '<td id="Wednesday1012" class="blacked"><small>Booked</small></td>';
  } else {
  echo '<td></td>';
  } ?>
 <?php if ($time >= 12 && $time < 14) {
  echo '<td id="Wednesday1214" class="blacked"><small>Booked</small></td>';
  } else {
  echo '<td></td>';
  } ?>
 <?php if ($time >= 14 && $time < 16) {
  echo '<td id="Wednesday1416" class="blacked"><small>Booked</small></td>';
  } else {
  echo '<td></td>';
  } ?>
 <?php if ($time >= 16 && $time < 18) {
  echo '<td id="Wednesday1618" class="blacked"><small>Booked</small></td>';
  } else {
  echo '<td></td>';
  } ?>
</tr>
```

Comment: buddy, im pretty sure that the suggested answer was different that mine.

Comment: I agree the question is different

Comment: Mat Some - Mysql_query is depreciated, look up mysqli as a replacement. I'm not sure what problems you have exactly but the initial connection to your Mysql database needs to be updated

Comment: Yes buddy, im well aware about the depreciated issues however everything is fine without using mysqli

Comment: if it works then it works :-)  Just don't forget to change if you upgrade php lol

Comment: sure will do buddy ;)